# Limit the number of results while looping through Laravel relation

Tags: php, model, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `beat.php` that extends Eloquent and has a function

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post')->withPivot('deleted_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

In the controller, I grab a Beat like this:

```
$beat = Beat::where('user_id', $data['owner']->id)->first();
```

And in the view, I loop through the posts like this:

```
@foreach ($beat->posts as $post)
    ...
@endforeach
```

The problem is that some "Beats" have hundreds of posts, causing PHP to run out of memory and the browser to hang. How can I limit the number of results returned?

---

I already tried:

```
public function posts($limit)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post')->withPivot('deleted_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take($limit);
}
```

And looped through it like this:

```
@foreach ($beat->posts(100) as $post)
    ...
@endforeach
```

But the loop just displayed nothing. Interestingly, it works when hardcoding `$limit` in the model and removing the parameter as such:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post')->withPivot('deleted_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(100);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `query scopes`? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I don't really see how that would help.

Comment: Same issue here:
return $this->belongsToMany('SomeClass')->take(20); - this for some reasons work only with number and also limit is for whole query - not for every parent so you can't select all parents with persistent number of related children... I think it's just not done yet.